# Javascript how to get the quarter of a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, timeout

Assuming that I'm trying to set a timeout for a token that will expire at time X.

X can be one hour, 10 minutes or even 1 day.

So basically I would need to set the timeout as follows:-

if the timestamp is 1 hour from now, then it should be in 45mins.

if the timestamp is 10 minutes from now, then it should be in ~ 7.5 minutes.

if the timestamp is 1 day from now, then it should be in 18 hours.

Assuming that this is my timestamp 1579019590

which gives the following translation

```
GMT: Tuesday, January 14, 2020 4:33:10 PM
Your time zone: Tuesday, January 14, 2020 11:33:10 AM GMT-05:00
Relative: In a day
```

Assuming that this is the expiration time of a token, that I received Monday  at 11:33:10 AM ( token lifespan is 1 day).

So I would need in my javascript to set a timeout that will fire at Monday 05:33:10 AM (6 hours before the 11:33:10 AM).

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: The timestamp appears to be seconds, ECMAScript is in milliseconds so you'll need to account for that.

Comment: @RobG Yeah I multiply by 1000 in my code after.

I'm trying to do a solution and will post here if I achieve something.. Reading about moment.js

Comment: There are plenty of [time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%5Bdate%5D+time+ago+format) date format questions here already. Use one of those to get going, then post whatever you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

I would identify the type of token coming in and have preset calculators to run to determine the amount of time to subtract.

You can identify the time difference between the now and the token. If it is greater than a day, have a function specific to finding the amount of hours between between then and now, calculate the percent difference needed, and modify your dateTime variable to the new value.

If the time difference is within an hour, calculate the minutes with your minute calculating function and find the percent difference there, then modify your dateTime variable.

And so on.

You can do this in a switch case statement for efficiency purposes.

Hope this helps!